# What is causing my home LAMP server to wait about 57 seconds before serving up a web page?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, localhost, lamp

I should preface this all by saying that I'm certainly not a sysadmin, or even a web designer. I've searched for an answer but most answers I've seen have to do with WAMP and DNS. Not my particular problem.

So, because I needed to resurrect an old website that won't run any more in the real world (oooold CMS with nasty security holes), I set up a LAMP server on my home network, on an old, 2009 MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 20.04.

The CMS (pixelpost, which was last updated in *2009*) is old enough that I had to install php 5.6 and mySQL 5.5.62 so that it would even run. Once I got everything installed and typed "localhost" into my web browser, nothing happened. For about a minute. Looking at the browser timeline, it seemed that nothing was being served at all for 56 or 57 seconds, then, the whole site showed up in about two seconds. It's the exact same trying from another computer on the local network.

The site is not trying to connect to resources (js, fonts, etc.) hosted elsewhere.

I've looked at the apache logs, there are no errors. I've looked at the mySQL logs (error and slow query), they have nothing to report. Nothing unusual in the PHP log either.

If it was slowly sending data across, I'd say, 'well, it's an old laptop with a super old database and php so, what do you expect?' but it seems to be waiting for something, failing, bailing or ignoring and then serving up the page.

I have no idea why that might be. Any ideas?